# Detecting the state of the alt/option key in a LWC Headless Quick Action

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, quickaction, lightning-quickaction, keyboard

I'd like my LWC [Headless Quick Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless) to behave differently when the alt/option key is held down. But the platform abstracts away the browser events and calls the `invoke` function with no additional information included:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class HeadlessSimple extends LightningElement {
  @api invoke() {
    console.log("Hi, I'm an action.");
  }
}
```

A [KeyboardEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp) or [MouseEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp) include an `altKey` property to signal that. What is the best way of obtaining that state for a Headless Quick Action? Does include an `onkeypress` listener work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rather verbose code works:

```
handleKeyDown;
handleKeyUp;
altKey = false;

connectedCallback() {
    this.handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.which === 18) this.altKey = true;
    };
    this.handleKeyUp = (event) => {
        if (event.which === 18) this.altKey = false;
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    if (this.handleKeyDown) window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    if (this.handleKeyUp) window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
}
```